# Filtering results with custom Expression in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Based on other questions and answers in SO, I tried using a custom expression to filter some results from my database but without success. It's about serching results into specific location by latitude, longitude and radius. When i run the query it throws an exception like the example bellow:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Post>
.Where(p => ExpressionUtils.IsInRadius(
    latA: p.Inner.Lat, 
    lngA: p.Inner.Lng, 
    latB: lat2, 
    lngB: lng2, 
    radius: radius))' could not be translated. 
Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly 
by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync().
...
```

The query looks as follow:

```
...

this.dbContext.Posts.Where(ExpressionUtils.CheckInRadius(x => x.Location.Lat, x => x.Location.Lng, model))
...
```

And the best type of implementation that I've found and changed for my case looks like this:

```
public static partial class ExpressionUtils
{
    public static Expression ReplaceParameter(this Expression expression, ParameterExpression source, Expression target)
    {
        return new ParameterReplacer { Source = source, Target = target }.Visit(expression);
    }

    public static Expression<Func<Post, bool>> CheckInRadius(Expression<Func<Post, decimal>> latSrcExp, Expression<Func<Post, decimal>> lngSrcExp, FilterPostsDTO model)
    {
        var entity = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Post));
        var latExp = latSrcExp.Body.ReplaceParameter(latSrcExp.Parameters[0], entity);
        var lngExp = lngSrcExp.Body.ReplaceParameter(lngSrcExp.Parameters[0], entity);

        Expression<Func<decimal, decimal, decimal, decimal, int, bool>> baseExpr
            = (latA, lngA, latB, lngB, radius) => IsInRadius(latA, lngA, latB, lngB, radius);

        var lat = baseExpr.Parameters[0];
        var lng = baseExpr.Parameters[1];
        var expr = baseExpr.Body
            .ReplaceParameter(lat, latExp)
            .ReplaceParameter(lng, lngExp);

        return Expression.Lambda<Func<Post, bool>>(expr, entity);
    }

    private static bool IsInRadius(decimal latA, decimal lngA, decimal latB, decimal lngB, int radius)
    {
        if (latB == 0 && lngB == 0 && radius == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }

        static double toRadians(decimal x) => (double)x * Math.PI / 180.0;

        var lat1 = toRadians(latA);
        var lon1 = toRadians(lngA);
        var lat2 = toRadians(latB);
        var lon2 = toRadians(lngB);
        var d_lat = lat2 - lat1;
        var d_lon = lon2 - lon1;
        var h = Math.Pow(Math.Sin(d_lat / 2), 2) + Math.Cos(lat1) * Math.Cos(lat2) * Math.Pow(Math.Sin(d_lon / 2), 2);
        var distance = Math.Abs(Math.Asin(Math.Sqrt(h)) * 6371 * 2);

        return distance <= radius;
    }

    class ParameterReplacer : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        public ParameterExpression Source;

        public Expression Target;

        protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
        {
            return node == Source ? Target : base.VisitParameter(node);
        }
    }
}
```

So obviously it doesn't work. Am I missing something or am I doing something wrong? Can somewone help?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: EF Core maps LINQ queries to SQL. It *can't* work with expressions that can't be mapped to SQL. Trying to hide the math functions behind `Expression<>` won't change this - Math.Pow still can't be translated

Comment: Besides, if you end up with such a complex expression, something's wrong. Even if you wrote this in SQL performance would be very, very bad. Besides, `InRadius` suggests you're trying to perform a spatial query. Unless you use the database's spatial features, such queries end up being *very* slow as they have to calculate distances for every single row. What are you trying to do?

Comment: EF Core 2.2 added [spatial data support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/spatial). You can use this with your database's spatial types eg SQL Server's geometry or geography, to perform spatial queries

Comment: How about calculating the "square" surrounding the "circle", query all entries in that square (should be much easier) and then filter the real "circle" in memory?

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos - I am currently reading about the spatial data but it looks like I have to scaffolding my db context from the SQL Server but I migrate it there, I'll try anyway.

Comment: Again, what are you trying to do? Simple `point in circle` queries are actually *faster* if you use a bounding box to filter individual `lat` and `lon` fields, the way Corak suggested. This is essentially a range query on `lat` or `lon`, something B-Tree indexes can easily accelerate. Once you reduce the number of results this way, it's easy to calculate how many of them are actually in the required radius from the center. NetTopologySuite can handle this on the client

Comment: @Corak - I understood that with the square, good point, but with the circle filtering later ...

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos - It's about some records with locations that I get from Google Maps APIs and I need to filter them by selected location (Lat & Lng) and radius. So it's better to calculate the square, then filter along with the other filters, then select the data I need, and then call the IsInRadius method. Is that right so far?

Answer (score 1):

Well you are trying to use Math.Pow, Math.Sin, Math.Cos etc. in the expression... I don't think most (sic. any?) database systems support these functions in SQL...

You can either .ToList() before applying the filter (although that will pull ALL results back to memory, and then filter them, so not ideal for performance), or you can try to use like a CLR SProc if using MSSQL, or the database-native spatial queries if your database system supports them

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to use the custom function "IsInRadius(....)" as part of WHERE clause, then below example works good.

```
public class Post
{
    public decimal latA;
    public decimal lngA;
    public decimal latB;
    public decimal lngB;
    public int radius;
}
```

I just created the list, instead of retreiving from database and then called the custom function in the filter, very similar to what you described.

```
List<Post> posts = new List<Post>()
{
    new Post() { latA = 10, latB = 12, lngA = 3, lngB = 4, radius = 4 },
    new Post() { latA = 13, latB = 11, lngA = 1, lngB = 12, radius = 1 },
    new Post() { latA = 15, latB = 4, lngA = 7, lngB = 8, radius = 6 },
    new Post() { latA = 17, latB = 2, lngA = 2, lngB = 9, radius = 2 },
};

List<Post> y0 = posts.ToList()
            .Where(x => (ExpressionUtils.IsInRadius(x.latA, x.lngA, 0, 0, x.radius)) == false)
            .ToList()
            ;
```